# ActiveRecord get array inside array with three tables

Tags: json, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to output a json string with the ActiveRecord system in the Codeigniter framework.
The right syntax for my json string need to be:

```
{
"data": [
    [
        {
            "name": "xxxx",
            "city": "xxx",
            "address": "xxx",
            "image": "xxx",
            "marketId": "1",
            "products": [
              "Id": "36",
              "productId": "36",
              "price": "120",
              "discounts": "1",
              "title": "xxx",
              "category": "2",
              "weight": "12.5",
              "code": "EA123",
              "isUnitized": "0",
              "description": "xxxx",
              "changed": "2014-04-08 15:09:16",
              "units": "xxx"
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

**Pay attention to the "products" array.**

But the string that i'm getting from the code is not right, here is the wrong string:

```
{
"data": [
    [
        {
            "name": "xxx",
            "city": "xxx",
            "address": "xx x",
            "image": "xxx",
            "marketId": "1",
            "Id": "36",
            "productId": "36",
            "price": "120",
            "discounts": "1",
            "title": "xxx",
            "category": "2",
            "weight": "12.5",
            "code": "EA123",
            "isUnitized": "0",
            "description": "xxx",
            "changed": "2014-04-08 15:09:16",
            "units": "xxx"
        }
    ]
]
```

You can see that the product array is't showing like an array but as a regular string inside the main array.

Here is the code that have I built:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('markets');
$this->db->where("markets.marketId", $marketId);
$this->db->join('linkedPrices', 'linkedPrices.marketId = markets.marketId');
$this->db->join('products', 'products.Id = linkedPrices.productId');
$this->db->order_by("linkedPrices.price", "DESC");
$output[] = $this->db->get()->result();
```

So you can see here the join between the table. The goal is to show the products tables as individual array inside the markets array as you can see at the top example of the json string.

Answer (score 0):

No not this way you gonna have array of products foreach your dataset it can be done by looping over your results and fetch the relevant product data

```
$result=new stdClass();
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('markets');
$this->db->where("markets.marketId", $marketId);
$this->db->join('linkedPrices', 'linkedPrices.marketId = markets.marketId');
$this->db->order_by("linkedPrices.price", "DESC");
$result = $this->db->get()->result();

foreach($result as $r){
$result->products=$this->db->select('*')
       ->from('products')
       ->where('id',$r->productId)
       ->get()
       ->result();
}
$output[]=json_encode($result);
```